# May Jews apply hand sanitizer on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, health-safety-shmira, hands-fingers, orach-chaim

In halacha, is there anything issur/prohibited for Jews to apply hand sanitizer on Shabbat? Or no, is it Muttar/permitted and not an issue of smearing?

Comment: It should be the same machlokes as liquid soap. R Moshe was machmir and R shlomo Zalman a was meikel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Many *poskim* permit since it is more like a liquid than a solid**.

[Tzurba mRabanan](https://www.tzurbaolami.com/)'s special COVID-19 issue brings a number of opinion (pp. 201ff)

- R Elyakim Levanon permits if the liquid drips down when placed on a slanted surface - and allows to dilute before Shabbos to make it drop
- R Dovid Heber of Star-K permits fluids of low viscosity (i.e., which pour fast)
- R Gedalia Schwartz, Av Beit Din of CRC, compares it to liquid soap which many poskim permit (Shemirat Shabbat 14:16, unlike Igrot Moshe OC I:113)
- R Asher Bush cites R Herschel Schachter who permits for the same reasons
- R Yitzchak Mordechai Rubin (author of the well-known sefer Orchot Shabbat) permits when the liquid spills easily